# What is this weed in my lawn and how can I get my grass back?

Tags: lawn, weed-control, grass, weeds

Essentially, along the edges of a new-to-me yard (edges of house, porch) -- I'm assuming from moisture retention -- a weedy/cloverish (I have no idea, clearly) thing is taking over.

This is a yard in North Texas / Fort Worth, if you're curious about environment.

Here is a picture of the grass/weed in question:

*click image for full size*

[image]

What is this stuff, and what is a good method if getting rid of it, while vitalizing the good grass?

Looking for ideas, or product + method recommendations.

Comment: Looks like a cool-season weed that's growing because your lawn is dormant for the winter. Can you get a closeup of the leaves? Also, are you averse to using a chemical control? Because That's gonna be the easiest method of control, although not necessarily the best for the environment.

Comment: If you upload a new photo, please use the "image" control above the editor (blue and green, looks like a tiny landscape painting), which will allow you to add the photo directly from your computer desktop.

Comment: From what I can see by zooming in as far as the picture allows, these might be dicots (seed leaves, not a particular type of weed) meaning that whatever it is is just starting to sprout. Your grass, on the other hand, is dormant.

Comment: Hard to tell without flowers, but it looks Ground Ivyish: http://turf.msu.edu/ground-ivy-control-for-home-lawns (*Glechoma hederacea*)

Comment: Your problem is NOT weeds.  Weeds are opportunists.  Bare soil or thin grass is like putting up neon signs for habitation by weeds.  What is your fertilization schedule?  When did you aerate last? What is your watering schedule?  How old is your lawn, was it seeded or sodded?  Do you ever mulch your lawn? And very important, what kind of grass do you have and how high do you mow??  It is difficult to get weeds when your grass is growing vigorously, has a deep root system, has plenty of top-growth for photosynthesis and is watered deeply and allowed to dry out in-between.

Comment: @NiallC., as a non-member, using an iPhone, I did not find that option on the site. I remember looking quite a bit for an image upload option, because external hosting sucks. Thanks for the edits to make it inline, I appreciate that.

Comment: @anonymouscoward You're welcome! Are you the OP? If you want to merge your accounts, use the [contact us](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/contact) link, then select "I need to merge user profiles" from the dropdown and follow the instructions.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, as the we need a closeup of the weed to make a definite id.